# MongoDB divide returns null when dividing by other variable

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to compute some numbers, but MongoDB returns null when using previous computed variable in $divide operator

This is the query:

```
db.apps.aggregate(

{$project : {
    a: {$multiply : [2,2]},
    b: {$divide: [5, "$a"]},
    c: {$divide: [5, 4]}

}})
```

Why "b" is null in the result:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5361173d93861f6e5239714e"),
            "a" : 4,
            "b" : null,
            "c" : 1.25
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("536192c1938652d039fa0051"),
            "a" : 4,
            "b" : null,
            "c" : 1.25
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

**EDIT:
Thanks to Neil comment, the solution is to have second stage $project**

```
db.apps.aggregate(

{$project : {
    a: {$multiply : [2,2]},
    b: {$divide: [5, "$a"]},
    c: {$divide: [5, 4]}

}},


{$project : {
    a: 1, c:1,
    b: {$divide: [5, "$a"]},   
}}

)
```

Comment: Umm **`$a`** is a projected value in the same stage. You cannot do that. You need another stage

Comment: Hmm, yep I got it, very newbie questions :D

Comment: Newbie is fine, just as long as you understood. And you did, so well done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variables in a `$project` step are always the fields of the **input** document of that step. You can not yet access any values computed in the same step. But you can access any computed values in a following $project step. So you can break your computation into two $project-steps like this:

```
db.apps.aggregate(
    [
        {   $project : {
                a: { $multiply : [2, 2] }
            }
        },
        {   $project : {
                a: 1,
                b: { $divide: [5, "$a"] }   
            }
        }
    ]
);
```

Answer (score 0):

now you can use let. Like that:

```js
db.apps.aggregate([{
    $project: {
        b: {
            $let: {
                vars: {
                    "a": {$multiply: [2,2]}
                },
                in: {$divide: [5, "$$a"]}
            }
        }
    }}
]);
```